# ROS2 messages stop 90s after network drops

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS2 Dashing with Fast-RTPS on a single-board computer running Ubuntu 18.04 server. It's mounted inside a waterproof enclosure. When the enclosure is in the air I can talk to it via wifi, and when it goes underwater the wifi connection drops. All ROS message traffic stops ~90 seconds after the network connection is lost.

I can easily reproduce this on my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04 desktop):

- in the 1st terminal run `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`
- in the 2nd terminal run `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener` -- starts reporting
- unplug the Ethernet cable, after ~90 seconds the listener stops reporting
- plug in the Ethernet cable, after a few seconds the listener starts back up

I've tried DHCP and static IP & DNS, but the behavior is the same. I don't see anything surprising in `journalctl -f`.

Interestingly, if I start sending messages while the network is down, it appears to ignore the state of the network:

- unplug the Ethernet cable
- in the 1st terminal run `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`
- in the 2nd terminal run `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener` -- starts reporting
- plug in the Ethernet cable, no change
- unplug the Ethernet cable, no change

Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326948/ros2-messages-stop-90s-after-network-drops/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2019-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-26**:
Related: #q325872.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like the loopback interface might not be configured to allow multicast traffic. Here's a [SO post about configuring this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007311/multicasting-on-the-loopback-device). You might find more information in [ros2/rmw_fastrtps#228](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/issues/228).

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-06-26**:
Thx... I'm investigating this now

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-06-27**:
You were right, loopback was not configured for multicast. I configured it using `route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo` and `ifconfig lo multicast`. This works great if I boot up with no network, enable multicast on loopback, then run the talker and listener. I can plug / unplug the Ethernet and it continues to work.

But if I boot up with the Ethernet plugged in, enable multicast on loopback, then start the talker and listener, it still stops 90 seconds after I unplug the Ethernet. The only way to restart communications is to kill all ROS nodes then restart them in the network-starved situation.

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-06-27**:
This might be a bug. Would you mind opening an issue on https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/issues ?

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2019-06-27**:
Opened: https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/issues/297